# `object:selected` event firing twice

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working with `JavaScript` and `fabricJs`, And i have this event,

```
canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);

function onObjectSelected() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString());
    canvas.getActiveObject().set({
        opacity: 0.7
    });
}
```

When i am consoling into function `onObjectSelected`, I can see its calling twice.

Also i tried,

```
stopPropagation
preventDefault
cancelBubble
```

But not working. I tried after remove

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set({
    opacity: 0.7
});
```

And working, What is the reason of this?

Comment: If you could plunker or place your code somewhere to test, people could help faster

Comment: sure @amol01 i will try to upload it in fiddle

Comment: @amol01 i just updated question, may be this could help you.

Comment: please add a fiddle. i don t think the cose can behave in this way. remove.parenthesis from the handler in the event assignment

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it without the parenthesis, like this?

```
canvas.on('object:selected', onObjectSelected);
```

Comment: I just tried little debugging, and i can see that i have piece of code in function `canvas.getActiveObject().set({
              opacity: 0.7
          });` which causing the issue.